# Wordpress admin post multiple filters not working individually

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-action

I've created custom post named talent, and created 3 admin filters based on custom fields, i.e., gender, travels from and vaccination.

Here is the code:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','talent_filter'); 

function talent_filter($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
    
    global $pagenow;
    
    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
        if ( isset( $_GET['gender'] ) && $_GET['gender'] !== '0' ) {
            $query->set('meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'gender',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['gender']),
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array( 
                'key' => 'travels_from',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['travels_from']),
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array( 
                'key' => 'vaccination',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['vaccination']),
                'compare' => '='
            )) );
        }
    }
}
```

The filter code works if I select a value for all the fields except default, however if I try to filter based on only one of the custom fields and keep other 2 filter values to default, it doesn't work

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arkdx.png)

Comment: Have you tried 'relation' => 'OR',

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul. Yes,Ive tried OR, but that will not work.

Comment: Please check the screenshot, there are 3 dropdown menus which work as filters. If I Dont select any value from GEnder dropdown, it should show all genders, however it doesnt work that way.

Comment: So don't add conditions to your meta query then, for those fields where there was no value selected in the filter form.